# What is the difference between > and space in css selector

Tags: css

I've seen two example,

> **.someclass > .inner{...}**

and

> **.someclass .inner{...}**

works the same way. Is there are any difference between them which i'm not seeing?

Comment: `>` matches immediate descendants. `:space:` matches descendants at any depth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first applies only to *immediate* children.  The second, to any descendant.

So given this CSS:

```
.someclass > .inner { color: red }
.someclass .inner { font-weight: bold }
```

the following applies:

```
<div class="someclass">
  <div class="inner">
     Bold and red
  </div>

  <div> 
    <div class="inner">
      Just bold.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.someclass>.inner {
  color: red
}

.someclass .inner {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass">
  <div class="inner">
    Bold and red
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="inner">
      Just bold.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info :) was helpful

Answer (score 4):

`.someclass > .inner{...}` 
 - only apply to ".inner" that are direct children to ".someclass".


`.someclass .inner{...}` - applies to any ".inner" that are inside ".someclass", even if there are elements between them.